@strapi/blocks-react-renderer , Delete semicolon in the library
I receive a series of texts from the API, some of which have only two empty quotations, and I want to put an enter instead of those quotations, but this library uses semicolon
@strapi/blocks-react-renderer": "^1.0.0**"

const enterParagraph: any = (data: any) => {
    const result: any = data.children.map((item: any, index: any) => {
      if (item) {
        const newItem: any =
          item.props.text === '' && item.props.text.split(/''/g).join('_');
        console.log(newItem);
        const nextItem: any = newItem;
        return nextItem;
      } else {
        // console.log('false');
      }
    });`your text`
    return (
      <>
        <div>{result}</div>;
      </>
    );
  };

 return(
        <BlocksRenderer
              content={item.text}
               blocks={{ paragraph: (children: any): any => enterParagraph(children) }}/>)


Update to the new version
This was a bug for this library that has been fixed
@strapi/blocks-react-renderer": "^1.0.1"
